# css display:table not displaying the border

Tags: fluid-layout, css, css-tables

```
<html>
    <style type="text/css">
        .table   { display: table;}
        .tablerow  { display: table-row; border:1px solid black;}
        .tablecell { display: table-cell; }
    </style>
    <div class="table">
        <div class="tablerow">
            <div class="tablecell">Hello</div>
            <div class="tablecell">world</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tablerow">
            <div class="tablecell">foo</div>
            <div class="tablecell">bar</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

According to my understanding, a black border should be drawn on each of the rows which I've specified via tablerow class. But the border doesn't come up.

And I wanted to change the height of a row. If I specify it with 'px' -- it works. But, if I give it with a % -- won't work.I tried the following

```
.tablerow  { 
    display: table-row;
    border:1px solid black;
    position: relative; //not affecting anything and the border disappears!! 
    //position: absolute; // if this is set,the rows overlaps and the border works
    height: 40%; // works only if specified in px and not in %
}
```

Something is going wrong somewhere, but I am not able to understand where. Please help!

Comment: have you tried specifying border for the cell elements? or is it not what you want?

Answer (score 182, accepted):

You need to add [`border-collapse: collapse;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse) to the `.table` class for it to work like this:

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">
    .table   { display: table; border-collapse: collapse;}
    .tablerow  { display: table-row; border: 1px solid #000;}
    .tablecell { display: table-cell; }
</style>
<div class="table">
    <div class="tablerow">
        <div class="tablecell">Hello</div>
        <div class="tablecell">world</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tablerow">
        <div class="tablecell">foo</div>
        <div class="tablecell">bar</div>
    </div>
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Table rows can't have a border attribute. You can get a border around each row by giving all cells a top and bottom border, and adding a class for the left-most and right-most cells with a left and right border respectively.

[JS fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/RwMJK/)

edit: I forgot about `border-collapse:collapse`. That will work too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `border` to the `tablecell` class.

Also, to make it look nice, you will need to add `border-collapse:collapse;` to the table class.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/4bvc2/

**EDIT**

As per the comment

> i'm applying a border to a div,it should get displayed right ?

Yes, but once you set it to display as a `table` that is how it will act... as a `table`, so you will then need to follow the css rules for displaying tables.

If you need to set the `border` only on the rows, use `border-top` and `border-bottom`  and then set specific classes for the leftmost and rightmost cells.

Comment: why cant i give the border for a row??

Comment: i'm applying a border to a div,it should get displayed right ?