# How to get table-row css and border property work together?

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS:

```
#center{
    display:table-row;
    border:solid #55A 1px;
    background-color:#AAF;
    height:100%;
}
```

Actually, the border property is just ignored. Why? How can I Fix it?
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZJh9y/)
Thanks

Comment: you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175049/css-displaytable-not-displaying-the-border

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a 'cell' to the table-row, for example:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="top">TOP</div>
    <div id="center">
        <div>CENTER</div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

Then the following CSS works:

```
#center{
    display:table-row;
}
#center > div {
    display: table-cell;
    border:solid #55A 1px;
    background-color:#AAF;
    height:100%;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ZJh9y/1/).

It's important to remember that the browser will render an element as you tell it to; so if you tell a `div` to `display: table-row` *it will display that way*; and a `table-row` does not have a `border`. `table-cell`s do, though, which is why I added the child `div` and assigned it that `display` property.

Answer (score 9):

Table rows can't have borders. Cells within a table row can, but the row itself cannot.

Comment: I am applying this CSS to a DIV

Comment: A `div` that you're having pretend to be a table-row (`tr`) element.

Comment: @skafandri You are applying `table-row` to it, so it behaves like one;

Comment: Genuine curiosity, not being snarky: do browsers "allow" for incorrect applying a border to a row (for proper tables, not just with table-row display property)? This test works in Firefox, but it might just be forgiving the bad style: http://jsfiddle.net/9QWj9/

Answer (score -1):

CSS

```
#content{
    display:table;
    border:solid black 1px;    
    width:250px;
    height:300px;
}
.center{
    display:table-row;
}
.center > div {
    display: table-cell;
    border:solid #55A 1px;
    background-color:#AAF;

}
#top{      
  border:solid red 1px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="center" style="height:50px">
        <div id="top">TOP</div>
    </div>
    <div class="center" style="height:100%">
        <div>CENTER</div>
    </div>
    <div class="center" style="height:50px">
        <div>BOTTOM</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZJh9y/4/)

Comment: This is NOT an answer. You have to imagine that it would be usable if the link went dead, and it is not.